# How to simultaneously sum and merge tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Forgive the possibly simply question, but I haven't been able to find anyone else asking how to do what I'm seeking to do.

Basically I have 4 spreadsheets comprised of stem density measurements taken at 4 quadrants around a point of interest. I need to sum the stem densities taken for each point at their respective quadrants and merge them with my main spreadsheet. I would just use the sum tool and do it manually, but each point has between 1 and 7 densities that need to be summed and they're not in numerical order, plus the dataset is several thousand rows. Pictures are linked below for clarification. Any help is appreciated!

Stem density quadrant datasets, UL/UR/LL/LR = Upper Left, Upper Right, etc.

[image: Stem Density Dataset]

Main Dataset, Summed stem density columns are empty to the right. Both datasets have corresponding Survey ID columns that should match them

[image: Main Dataset]

Comment: This looks like a perfect time for `SUMIF()` - have you tried using this yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click into one of the data cells the UL tab and use **Data - Get & Transform - From Table**. This will convert it to a table if not already, then open up a Power Query editor window. From that window, click **Add Column - Custom Column**, change the new column name to "Quadrant" and the custom column formula to `"UL"`. Click OK to close that dialog box and return to the Power Query editor window. In the right sidebar, change the query name to `UL`. Then click the tiny arrow in the ribbon's **Home - Close & Load** button on the ribbon, choose **Close & Load To...**, then load to "Only Create Connect" and click "Load". (This creates a query but no results are stored.)
2. Click into one of the data cells in the UR tab and use **Data - Get & Transform - From Table**. From that window, click **Add Column - Custom Column**, change the new column name to "Quadrant" and the custom column formula to `"UR"`. Click OK to close that dialog box and return to the Power Query editor window. In the right sidebar, change the name to `UR`.
3. Repeat for the LL tab.
4. Repeat for the LR tab.
5. Edit any of those queries again, opening it in the Power Query editor window again.
6. From the tiny dropdown on the **Home - Append Queries** ribbon button, choose **Append Queries as New**, and append your four queries together.
7. In the right sidebar, name your new query.
8. Choose **Home - Choose Columns** from the ribbon. Deselect all but the Survey ID, Stems, and Quadrant columns.
9. Click the "Quadrant" column title to select that column, then choose **Transform - Pivot Column** from the ribbon. In the dialog box, choose the Stems column, and in the advanced part, choose to average.
10. Close & Load this to a new tab in your workbook. (You can delete the tab later if you want this to be connection-only as well.)

Now you have options! You can close & load this query to your worksheet then use formulas, or you can create a query of your main data set minus the UL, UR, LL, LR columns, then merge them together by Survey ID using the Power Query Editor's **Home - Merge Queries** ribbon button.